# How can i add new combobox based on selection of prev combobox in extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have the combobox in Extjs

`Ext.form.field.combobox`

Now i want that if someone selection option 1 or 2 then i shows another combox  and hide it if some other option is selected

How can i do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially keep your `combobox2` hidden.

In select listener of `combobox1` make:

```
if(combobox1.getValue() ==1 || combobox1.getValue() ==2)

 combobox2.show();

else

 combobox2.hide();


form.doLayout();
```